# jqgrid ASP.NET MVC -- getting data right for the grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, jqgrid

Here is my dilemma,

I have not been able to manipulate my data to a form fitting to `jqgrid` standards. This is my first time using the `jqgrid` and I've spent a lot of time reading up on it.

My js code is as follows:

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    url: '/Home/ListContacts/',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames: ['First Name', 'MI', 'Last Name'],
    colModel: [{
            name: 'First Name',
            index: 'FName',
            width: 40,
            align: 'left'
        },
        {
            name: 'MI',
            index: 'MInitial',
            width: 40,
            align: 'left'
        },
        {
            name: 'Last Name',
            index: 'LName',
            width: 400,
            align: 'left'
        }
    ],
    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
    sortname: 'Id',
    sortorder: "desc",
    repeatitems: false,
    viewrecords: true,
    imgpath: '/scripts/themes/basic/images',
    caption: 'My first grid'
});
```

What I'm getting from the database:

```
[
    ["4", "Jenna", "Mccarthy"],
    ["56", "wer", "weoiru"]
]
```

Now correct me if I am wrong, but the index: in my colModel refers to the column names in my database right?

Could  someone point to a reference that is straight forward or just start me off with this I would be most grateful.

Comment: have you got it working?

Answer (score 3):

Index is what will be passed to the controller in the sidx query string parameter to indicate which column should be used for sorting when you click on that column header in the grid. Name is the property name in the returned json for the data for that column. For obvious reasons, these are often the same. I have a long series of posts, [starting here](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/04/14/38200/), which explains all of this in great detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, it helped a great deal my solution is now working and I will be able to play with it to see all of what is going on. Thanks for the great tutorial and break down of the info.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt your column model be [id, first, lastname] ? Anyway there is [Phil Haack's post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx) and I have one on [enabling editing](http://ericdotnet.wordpress.com/2009/05/02/editing-in-jqgrid-with-aspnet-mvc/).

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have the 'First Name' and 'Last Name'. The column 'MI' is missing in your JSON-data
**what im getting from the database: [["4","Jenna","Mccarthy"],["56","wer","weoiru"]]**

the first field in the JSON is the id, right? The second is the 'First Name' and the third  should be 'MI', so on.